# How do I cool the output water from the water sieve?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

Just playing the most recent update of [Oxygen Not Included](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_Not_Included) (Expressive) and the water coming out of my water sieves is really hot. It used to come out at 70F and now it is going in at 80F and coming out at 104F. Bad news.

I have no access to a cold biome, what can I do to cool the water?

Answer (score 1):

Water sieve has **fixed temperature output at 40C = 104F**, and temperature of the sieve itself or the feeding water or sand doesn't affect it. It's more like of a feature than a bug.

You can use this property for your advantage - just hook the sieve output to 1 **aquatuner**  ( ideally by placing the aquatuner in an isolated chamber where also polluted water is stored) and you'll get nice clean water about 26 C which is nice for your bristle blossom farms

Comment: I tried using an aquatuner but it got hot really fast and started to break almost immediately.

Comment: @TylerDurden: use the polluted water as a coolant for your aquatuner.  The water sieve will "delete" the heat the aquatuner creates.

Comment: yes. As i stated in the response, the aquatuner should be in a chamber where polluted water is also stored

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate as a recent update fixed this bug.